# Initialize array after using it

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So here's my code :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test9 {
public static void main (String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String invoer = null;
    String[] sorteerArray = new String[25];

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {

        System.out.print (i + 1 );
        invoer = sc.nextLine();
        sorteerArray[i] = invoer;

        if ("".equals(invoer)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    Arrays.sort(sorteerArray);

    for (String sorteerArrayOutput : sorteerArray) {
        System.out.println (sorteerArrayOutput);
    }
}
}
```

I get a NullPointerException, because when I try to sort my array there are nulls in the array, that's because I initialized my array with 25. I know what the problem is, I just don't how to fix it. Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Hi! In which line do you get the Exception?

Comment: @ItamarG3 On line 22, which contains "Arrays.sort(sorteerArray);"

Comment: Please paste the stack-trace.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:321)
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1246)
 at Test9.main(Test9.java:22)
C:\Users\larsv\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: Paste it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can initialize the string array with "".
Eg-

```
for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
    sorteerArray[i]="";
}
```

OR
you can use a Collection i.e. a List to have a dynamic size array.

Comment: This comment was very helpful, now it seems very logical and I would definitely implement this in the future, again, thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can

1. Truncate the array to remove the `null` elements

   ```
   String[] sorteerArray = new String[25];
   int nbValue = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
       System.out.print (i + 1 );
       invoer = sc.nextLine();
       sorteerArray[i] = invoer;
       nbValue++;
       if ("".equals(invoer)) {
           break;
       }
   }
   sorteerArray = Arrays.copyOf(sorteerArray, nbValue);
   Arrays.sort(sorteerArray);
   ```
2. Use a `List`

   ```
   List<String> sorteerList= new List<String>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
       System.out.print (i + 1 );
       invoer = sc.nextLine();
       sorteerList.add(invoer);
       if ("".equals(invoer)) {
           break;
       }
   }
   sorteerList.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Think what happens if you enter `""` in the third string.

So your loop breaks, with some of the values in the array still being `String`'s default value, which in this case is `null`.

This makes it so that `sort` attempts to compare `null` to other strings (you can read online how `.sort` works).

To fix this, you should add this before your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sorteerArray.length; i++) {
    sorteerArray[i]="";
}
```

If you go through you code with a debugger, you'll be able to see that all the values in the array, after the `""`, are `null`. So when `sort` is running, it'll compare between values of the array, and at some point get to `null`, causing a `NullPointerException`.

The code I have written above will *initialize* the array with empty strings, so that they can be compared.

Comment: Do correct me if I'm wrong. So basically I am creating a standard value for the array, and if the input is not empty, I am overriding that value?

Comment: @Lars Precisely!

Answer (score 1):

In scenarios like this, you could use ArrayList instead arrays, as explained below

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String invoer = null;
        List<String> sorteerArray = new ArrayList<>(25);

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {

            System.out.print(i + 1);
            invoer = sc.nextLine();
            sorteerArray.add(invoer);

            if ("".equals(invoer)) {
                break;
            } 
        }

        Collections.sort(sorteerArray);

        for (String sorteerArrayOutput : sorteerArray) {
            System.out.println(sorteerArrayOutput);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting read, I will use this in the future since this sounds a lot easier than an array, thanks!